# Error "Failed to read: org.bluez.Error.Failed"

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

using Debian linux platform.
using BLEdevice [SensorBug with Pill Case- Bluetooth 4.0 Wireless ]
using Bluez5.40

Trying with bluetoothctl tool to connect,pair and read characteristics.

I am able to connect, trust, and pair with the device.
I am able to select-attribute of a particular characteristics.

But when I tried "read" command, I am getting the following error

[SensorBug109B6F:/service003e/char0047]# **attribute-info**

Characteristic - Vendor specific

```
    UUID: 9dc84838-7619-4f09-a1ce-ddcf63225b34
    Service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EC_FE_7E_10_9B_6F/service003e
    Flags: read
    Flags: write-without-response
    Flags: write
    Flags: authenticated-signed-writes
```

[SensorBug109B6F:/service003e/char0047]# **read**

**Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EC_FE_7E_10_9B_6F/service003e/char0047
Failed to read: org.bluez.Error.Failed**

Has anyone tried reading characteristics using bluetoothctl commands?

What I am missing here?

Comment: Can some one please help

Comment: Following is the  Hci dump when I select Read:                                                                                                      > ACL data: handle 18 flags 0x02 dlen 9
    ATT: Error (0x01)
      Error: Insufficient authentication (5)
      Read req (0x0a) on handle 0x002e
< ACL data: handle 18 flags 0x00 dlen 7
    ATT: Read req (0x0a)
      handle 0x002e
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 18 packets 1

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but sadly still relevant. Vendor Specific characteristics are services that are not open to be freely accessed. This means that they are to be implemented by proprietary applications or compatible products. There are many fitness devices, phones (specially iPhones), etc. that present this characteristics e.g. Garmin watches.